# how to draw this shape with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, draw, shapes

I have a chat page, in the messages I need to draw a custom shape
so how to draw this shape with flutter, ignore the purple color it's from screen shot

```
Container(
  height: 0.1*MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  color: Color(0xffFFC20F),
  child: Text('some thing'),
)
```

[image: row]

Comment: Use `CustomClipper<Path>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should help you. You can modify the values according to your need.

```
class CustomClip extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size){
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(10,0);
    path.lineTo(10,size.height/2 - 10);
    path.lineTo(0,size.height/2);
    path.lineTo(10,size.height/2 + 10);
    path.lineTo(10,size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width,size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width,0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper clipper){
    return false;
  } 
}
```

Then you can use it in your code as

```
ClipPath(
  clipper:CustomClip(),
  child:Container(width:300,height:100,color:Colors.yellow),
);
```